# Are document ids unique throughout a RethinkDB database?

Tags: rethinkdb

That is, based on a given id, can I uniquely identify one and only one document from any table in a RethinkDB database?

Also, say I delete a document with an id, what are the chances for that id to appear again in the table at a later insert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field `id` is by default the primary key. Two documents in the same table cannot share the same primary key.

By default, if you do not provide a value for the primary key, RethinkDB will randomly generate a UUID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

The probably of having an id re-appear is `1/2^128` (every time you regenerate an id). Basically it's pretty safe.

Comment: I know that the primary keys within a table are guaranteed to be unique; was just curious about the case of UUID's in the whole database. Thank you for answering!